# fetch records from table ordered by column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column to maintain the state of the record. i.e.

```
-----------------------------
| id  | desc      | state    |
-----------------------------
| 1   | desc 1    | Complete |
| 2   | desc 2    | Open     |
| ... | ...       | ...      |
-----------------------------
```

I want fetch the records in the order of 'Open' followed by 'Complete'. Can I get this done using one SQL query? If so, how should I write it?

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: @fa06 it is 5.7.19

Comment: Note that desc is a reserved word

Comment: use order by  with case expression

Comment: If the answer you've accepted is fine for you, then you could just use `ORDER BY state DESC`. And though it kind of "smells"  a little bit, it can at least use an index (if present).

Comment: If I use order by desc, I do not have control over the way the records are returned. There are many states other than these two and the order of records to be returned doesn't always be in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with the ORDER BY statement and [FIELD](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php) function:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY FIELD(state, 'Open', 'Complete')
```

Comment: Be careful - If the `state` is nether 'Open' nor 'Complete' `FIELD(..)` will return `0` and sort the row first.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for pointing it out. But the way it return records matches my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
order by decode (state, 'Open', 1, 'Complete', 2, 3)
```

Comment: Is there any documentation of the used function `decode()` available? Please post a reference.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't use mySql, but here it say it works https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/decode().php

Comment: MySQL's `DECODE()` expects exactly two parameters and is doing something completely different. I guess your query is for *Oracle*. You should at least note that in your "answer". But in first instance you shouldn't answer MySQL questions with Oracle code.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you are right, I should check before writing. I apologize.